# Python Multiprocessor and a list of variables to be passed to a function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Okay, so I've never used the python multiprocessing library, and I don't really know how to word my search. I read the docs for the library, and I have tried searching for examples of my problem and I couldn't find anything.
I have a list of file names (~2400), a dictionary (called cond, and is a global), and a function. I want to run my function on each processor, and each time the function is running it is using one of the file names as the variable. So I want it to be running 4 processes, 1 for each processor, and it should work its way through the list, when one function ends it carries onto the next item in the list, and each of those functions are going to be updating a single shared dictionary.

Psudofunction code:

```
def PSC(fnom):
    f = open(fnom,"r")
    r = xml.dom.minidom.parse(f)
    cond[fnom] = otherfunc(r)
    f.close()
```

So, a) is it possible to use multiprocessing on this function, and b) if it is, what method from the multiprocessing library would be able to handle it, c) if you're extra nice, how do I iterate through a list passing each item as a arg each time.

musings about the way it would work (psudo bulls*** code):

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    name_list = name_list_func()
    method = multiprocessing.[method]() #no idea what method
    method.something(target=PSC, iter=name_list) #no idea either
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy, except for the "single shared dictionary" part.  Processes don't share memory.  That's a lie, but it's one you should believe at first ;-)  I'm going to keep the dict in the main program here, because that's **far** more efficient than any actual way of sharing the dict across processes:

```
NUM_CPUS = None # defaults to all available cores

def PSC(fnom):
    return fnom, len(fnom)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp
    pool = mp.Pool(NUM_CPUS)
    list_of_strings = list("abcdefghijklm")
    cond = {}
    for fnom, result in pool.imap_unordered(PSC, list_of_strings):
        cond[fnom] = result
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print cond
```

That's code you can actually run.  Plugging in file-opening cruft, XML parsing, etc, doesn't change any of what you need to get the multiprocessing part working right.

In current Python 3, this can be made a little simpler.  The code here is for Python 2.

Note that instead of `imap_unordered()`, you could also use `imap()` or `map()`.  `imap_unordered()` gives the implementation the most freedom to arrange things as efficiently as possible, although so far the implementation isn't really smart enough to take much advantage of that.  Looking ahead ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and I went with the imap_unordered(), and I'm stuck in 2.7 because of ArcPy.